# Bash Tab Completion Suggests Hidden SVN Files

Tags: bash, svn

When using tab completion, I keep getting suggestions for .svn files, so, using `ls`, my output looks like this:

```
[spaceplace]$ ls src/
main/ .svn/ 
[spaceplace]$ ls src/
main/ .svn/ 
[spaceplace]$ ls src/
main/ .svn/ 
[spaceplace]$ ls src/main/
java/      resources/ .svn/      
[spaceplace]$ ls src/main/
java/      resources/ .svn/
```

The .svn files don't show up when I just use `ls`, so I don't know why they show up when I use tab complete.  The issue only seems to exist with the .svn files and no other hidden files, which seems weird.  How can I get these files to not show up when I am using tab complete?

Comment: Because glob-completion of null doesn't exclude hidden files...

Comment: So why don't `.` and `..` show up then?

Comment: Because it excludes them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found out a way to do it; in my .bashrc I added the line `bind 'set match-hidden-files off'`.  Now all the files beginning with "." don't show up unless you explicitly specify it.

Answer (score 3):

Bash allows to specify which files or directories to ignore in tab completion based on extensions, e.g. to ignore all files or directories named `*.svn`

```
$ export FIGNORE=$FIGNORE:.svn
```

Depending on how your files are usually named this shouldn't clash too much (at least it worked well for me).

Comment: Will that command hide all files named *.svn in tab completion even if I explicitly specify it?  For example if I say `ls /test/.sv`, will it complete to `ls /test/.svn`?

Comment: No, it won't, but once you entered `.sv` I would argue pressing a single `n` is even more ergonomic than going to `TAB`. But you are right, when ignoring longer names this can become cumbersome (I have in there only `CVS` right now).

Comment: Thanks!  I just wanted to know what the command would do before I tried it.

Comment: LOL @fvrghl, that took more effort than copying the text, cd'ing to a dir with .svn dirs in it, pasting and then typing `ls <tab><tab>` :)

Answer (score 0):

The tab completion does not exclude hidden files. It is acting as intended. If you do a `ls -a` it will show the hidden files.

It is worth noting that any files/folders that start with a . are hidden files. Command line assumes that you will need access to these files which is why it is suggesting them in the auto complete.

Comment: I don't want to see the hidden files though